# How does this change to April O'Neil in the Archie comics happen?

Tags: teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles, april-o-neil

I've been reading up on the character April O'Neil, and the [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_O%27Neil#Archie_Comics) says that in the Archie Comics:

> In the winter 1994 Archie Special, April was mutated into a turtle herself.

How does this mutation happen?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This all happens in *Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles Adventures Special* issue 11 otherwise known as *Winter 1994 Archie Special* as in the Wikipedia article. April learns that Splinter is somewhat depressed and can't remember what it was like being human. After some research she learns of the "Genterprises Corporation" who appear to have developed an "anti-toxic waste serum" which they claim can reverse harmful mutations.

[image: April researches a cure on her computer as explained above and then travels to the company now renamed: Mergenterprises]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

She goes into the building asking around and is unceremoniously chucked out because they don't give interviews anymore and the tours have been suspended. Upon leaving the building she notices Tim London, one of Shredder's men entering the building with a barrel of toxic waste and so decides to sneak in. She eventually finds out there are Grems working inside the building and after a very brief chase is captured and placed in a cell.

[image: April and others are captured in some cells, the scientist from earlier and some Grems are outside. They bring in some test animals and expose them to the subjects. A Grem then pours some mutagen into a container from the toxic waste barrel]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

This mutagen is then sprayed on April who mutates into a turtle.

[image: The mutagen is sprayed on April bu a Grem, she screams Noooo as she mutates into a She-Hulk like character initially] [image: April is transformed into the turtle, whilst the receptionist who was also caught with her is transformed into a creature similar to Splinter]
<sub>*Click images to enlarge.*</sub>

Comment: Is it me or does that first panel imply April and the girl are in a relationship?

Comment: They are [close friends](https://turtlepedia.fandom.com/wiki/Oyuki_Mashimi), and apparently roommates.

Comment: "Splinter is somewhat depressed and can't remember what it was like being human"  But but but Splinter was mutated from a *rat*.  He never was human in the first place, so he has nothing to remember.